# How can I play some MP3 or OGG file on the JustBoom DAC HAT?

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I recently installed a JustBoom DAC HAT on my Raspberry Pi 3, but I can't make it play a sound by using ALSA or PulseAudio. `alsamixer` lets me configure the HAT, apparently without problems, but `test-speaker` complains it can't access the sound device (ALSA) or can't connect to the PulseAudio server when it's running (connection refused).

Here are the steps I've taken after installing the HAT:

1. Removed the on-board sound device from /boot/config.txt:

   dtparam=audio=off
   dtoverlay=justboom-dac
2. Used the following .asoundrc for ALSA:

   pcm.!default {
       type hw
       card 0
       device 0
   }

   ctl.!default {
       type hw
       card 0
   }

…and for PulseAudio:

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 0
}
```

3. For PulseAudio, changed the /etc/pulse/default.pa file as follows:

   load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
   load-module module-zeroconf-publish
4. Ran alsamixer and set volumes of both channels to 100%. For PulseAudio, I started the server as daemon (which started without errors): `pulseaudio -D`
5. Ran `speaker-test`, which crashed both in the ALSA, and in the PulseAudio config: With PulseAudio, it said:

   pi@autoradio:~ $ speaker-test

   speaker-test 1.0.28

   Playback device is default
   Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
   Using 16 octaves of pink noise
   ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:     Connection refused

   Playback open error: -111,Connection refused

What's wrong here? Does anybody have a hint for me? Thank you.

UPDATE: Using ALSA in debug mode (by adaprint the /etc/libao.conf file) and trying to play an OGG sound file, I get this:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ ogg123 -v Emergency_Alert_System_Attention_Signal_20s.ogg
debug: Loaded driver null (built-in)
debug: Loaded driver wav (built-in)
debug: Loaded driver raw (built-in)
debug: Loaded driver au (built-in)
debug: Loading driver plugins from /usr/lib/ao/plugins-4...
debug: Loaded driver oss
debug: Loaded driver pulse
debug: Loaded driver nas
debug: Loaded driver esd
debug: Loaded driver alsa
debug: Testing drivers to find playback default...

Audio Device:   Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA) output
Author:   Bill Currie <bill@taniwha.org>/Kevin Cody, Jr. <kevinc@wuff.dhs.org>
Comments: Outputs to the Advanced Linux Sound Architecture version 0.9/1.x

Playing: Emergency_Alert_System_Attention_Signal_20s.ogg
Ogg Vorbis stream: 1 channel, 44100 Hz
Vorbis format: Version 0
Bitrate hints: upper=-1 nominal=96000 lower=-1 window=0
Encoded by: Xiph.Org libVorbis I 20030909
Encoder: Cool Edit
ao_alsa debug: Trying to open ALSA device 'default'
ao_alsa debug: snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels() failed.
ao_alsa debug: Unable to open ALSA device 'default'
ao_alsa ERROR: Unable to open ALSA device 'default' for playback => Invalid argument
ERROR: Cannot open device alsa.
```

Comment: To rule out the obvious have you rebooted?

Comment: Sure I have, even several times!

Answer (score 1):

OK, after consulting [quite a detailed tutorial](http://www.volkerschatz.com/noise/alsa.html), I've managed to find a solution myself, which looks like this: I added a virtual "plug" device to my ALSA config, which allows for playback of mono soundtracks:

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug

  slave {
    pcm "hw:0,0"
    format S32_LE
    channels 2
    rate 192000
  }
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

Explanation: The default device is now a "plug" device, which itself uses the JustBoom card (hw:0,0) as a slave. The two output channels are stated in the config, so that a mono sound stream can be duplicated (otherwise I would continue getting this lousy error message). The other lines (32 bit width + 192 kbit/s sampling rate) have been added for better sound quality.

I put this config into the `/etc/asound.conf` config file and deleted the `.asoundrc` files.

What I also had to do, was to reduce the volume of the "digital" output to 40% in order not to overscan, thereby causing a very distorting sound.